# Select Date and Numeric columns only

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

Is there an efficient way to select Date and numeric columns in R?

```
df <- data.frame(
    Date=c("10/11/2012","10/12/2012"),
    AE=c(1211,100),
    Percent=c(0.03,0.43),
    Name = c("A", "B")
)
```

As such I can use `is.numeric` function to check if a column is numeric or not and then use one of several ways to subset, but is there a function to check if a column is date and how to use multiple conditions for subseting.

I found that there is a funciton `is.Date` in lubridate package but it did not work

```
#does not work
df <- df %>% 
    select_if(is.numeric|is.Date)
```

Answer (score 2):

`dplyr` verbs for selection allow various methods of providing the conditionals>

- raw functions, as in `is.numeric`, which will be called with the column data (a vector) as its one argument;
- anonymous functions (R style), as in `function(x) is.numeric(x) | inherits(x, "Date")`;
- what is called a "purrr style lambda" using R formulas (`~`), which seems to be just a more compact form of the base R anon-func, but there are a some differences, namely you use `.` or `.x` as a placeholder for the column data, as in the answer below

```r
df %>%
  select_if(~ is.numeric(.) | inherits(., "Date"))
#     AE Percent
# 1 1211    0.03
# 2  100    0.43
```

Since your first column is not actually a date, let's fix that

```r
# df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y")
df %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format="%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
  select_if(~ is.numeric(.x) | inherits(.x, "Date"))
#         Date   AE Percent
# 1 2012-10-11 1211    0.03
# 2 2012-10-12  100    0.43
```

Comment: this works, what does ~ do? I have seen it several times but don't know when to use it and when not ? is there a guide ?

Comment: in general, it's for formulas. In R, a formula actually preserves information about the environment in which it was defined ... though this does not need to be used. It is not immediately evaluated, and its data is not immediately usable (for basic stuff), it takes a little bit of work to be able to use it in the context of either (1) the original environment, or (2) other things. `purrr`-style lambdas are more of this latter thing, where they use it for something else.

Comment: You'll often see `~` used in regressions (`lm(mpg ~ disp, data=mtcars)`), tabulation (`xtabs(~cyl + gears, data=mtcars)`), and plotting (`plot(y ~ x, data=somedf)`).